# JPA Repositories and blocking I/O

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a problem where I need to perform several slow HTTP requests on a separate thread after having written to the database using a JpaRepository. The problem is that `doActualJob()` blocks while waiting for a series of futures to resolve. This seems to prevent the underlying Hibernate session from closing, causing the application to run out of connections shortly after.

How do I write this function so the database connection isn't kept open while doing the blocking I/O? Is it even possible using JpaRepositories, or do I need to use a lower level API like EntityManager/SessionFactory?

```java
@Service
class SomeJobRunner {

    private final SomeJobRepository mSomeJobRepository; //extends JpaRepository

    @AutoWired
    public SomeJobRunner(final SomeJobRepository someJobRepository) {
        mSomeJobRepository = someJobRepository;
    }

    @Async
    public void doSlowJob(final long someJobId) {
        SomeJob someJob = mSomeJobRepository.findOne(someJobId);
        someJob.setJobStarted(Instant.now());
        mSomeJobRepository.saveAndFlush(someJob);

        doActualjob(); // Synchronous job doing several requests using Unirest in series

        someJob = mSomeJobRepository.findOne(someJobId);
        someJob.setJobEnded(Instant.now());
        mSomeJobRepository.saveAndFlush(someJob);
}
```

Comment: Do you require it to be transactional, I mean wait with commit until slow job finishes?

Comment: The start date needs to be written to the database to mark the job as started, so that the same job is not executed twice.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to use an existing solution, ie. quartz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well -  non-blocking database IO is not possible in Java/JDBC world in a standard way .To put it simply - your Spring data repository would be eventually using JPA ORM Implementation ( likes of Hibernate) which in turn will use JDBC to interact with the database which is essentially blocking in nature. There is work being done on this currently by Oracle ([Asynchronous Database Access API](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/jdbc-next:-a-new-asynchronous-api-for-connecting-to-a-database) ) to provide a similar API as JDBC but non-blocking. They intend to propose this as a standard. Also there is an exciting and  parallel effort by Spring guys on this namely [R2DBC – Reactive Relational Database Connectivity](https://github.com/r2dbc). They have actually integrated this with Spring data as well ([link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc)) so that may help you integrate in your solution. A good tutorial by Spring on this can be found [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/07/reactive-programming-and-relational-databases).

EDIT: As of 2022 Hibernate has [reactive](https://hibernate.org/reactive/) option as well

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to write in the database using a separate [JTA transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html). Do do so, define a methode like

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveJobStart(final long someJobId) {
    SomeJob someJob = mSomeJobRepository.findOne(someJobId);
    someJob.setJobStarted(Instant.now());
    mSomeJobRepository.saveAndFlush(someJob);
}
```

Of course it is not quite the same. If `doActualjob()` fails, in your case, the database won't persist the start date. In my proposal, it will persist it. To compensate, you need to remove the start date in a `catch` bloc in *doSlowJob*, within a new transaction, and then re`throw` the exception.